# jquery Add class to parent LI

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">
</ul>
```

I want to detect if some `li` has the class `active` then addClass `visible` to `ul`.

I was trying this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var check = $( "li" ).hasClass( "active" );
        if(check){
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('visible');
        }
    });
```

But is not working,

Comment: `$('li.active').closest('ul').addClass('visible')`  You're making it harder than it has to be

Comment: Your issue revolves around your incorrect usage of `this`.  The `this` in your snippet is not the li.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar that's what I need it, why didn't you put it as an answer

Comment: I'm always hesitant to put a one liner as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var check = $( "li" ).hasClass( "active" );
    if(check){
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('visible');
    }
});
```

The primary issue here is that `this` is not what you think it is.  Though, since you are trying to do `parent('li')`, I'm not entirely sure what you think it is.  You seem to think it is a child of the li.  But it's not.  Most likely since it is in the document ready, it's the `window`.

In any case, this logic can be reduced.

```
$('li.active').closest('ul').addClass('visible');
```

Rather than selecting li and then testing if they have a class, **select** the elements that do have the class.  Then using `closest('ul')` to go up to their parents contextually, you can then add the class to the parent uls.